# ASP.net Core MVC testing / make controller return a string?

Tags: c#, testing, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm currently at the point where I want to write a test for my ASP.net Core MVC project.

The problem is that I currently put this code into my view, which isn't really suitable for testing.

A snippet of the code is as follow:

```
@if (Model.MealDays != null)
{
    bool boolSaltLess = false;

        @foreach (var c in Model.MealDays)
        {
                @{
                    if (@c.Meal.Saltless == true)
                    {
                        boolSaltLess = true;
                    }
                }
        }
    <div>
        <p><b>Missing meal diets:</b></p>
        @if (boolSaltLess == false)
        {
            <p style="color:red">A saltless meal!</p>
        }
   </div>
}
```

My initial question is if I could move this code into my controller, and what result I would need to return from my controller to display this information in my View.

```
    public ViewResult DayDetail(int id)
    {
        Day d = repository.Days.Where(Day => Day.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
        IEnumerable<MealDay> md = mdRepository.MealDays;

        foreach (MealDay i in md)
        {
            i.Day = repository.Days.Where(Day => Day.ID == i.DayID).FirstOrDefault();
            i.Meal = mRepository.Meals.Where(Meal => Meal.ID == i.MealID).FirstOrDefault();

        }

        return View(d);
    }
```

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include an additional property in the view model to pass the data to the view

```
public bool Saltless { get; set; }
```

Move the logic into the controller action and

```
//...

model.Saltless = model.MealDays?.Any(c => c.Meal.Saltless);

return View(model);

//...
```

In the view, now it is a simple matter of check the property

```
@if (Model.MealDays != null) {    
    <div>
        <p><b>Missing meal diets:</b></p>
    @if (Model.Saltless == false)
    {
        <p style="color:red">A saltless meal!</p>
    }
    </div>
}
```

And it allows the logic to be verified via unit tests on the Controller action

Comment: I added my controller to the original question, where I assume I can't use "return View(model);" , since "model" would be "d" (a specific day) in my case. Any thoughts on this, a viewbag possibly?

Comment: Yeah a view bag would need to be used in that case. I had made an assumption about the model based on how it was being used in the view.

Comment: I'll try with all the info you granted! Thanks for now

Answer (score 0):

The logic is unnecessary in the first place. Just do:

```
@if (!Model.MealDays.Any(x => x.Meal.Saltless))
{
    <p style="color:red">A saltless meal!</p>
}
```

Besides, tests are about results, not logic or implementation. In other words, the test passes if when all the meals are saltless, the response contains "A saltless meal!" and doesn't if any of the meals are saltless. That means whatever logic you had works, and that's all that matters.

Comment: This would work, but makes it "impossible" to test via the controller right?

Comment: See my update. All you should be testing is that given a certain data set, the right thing ends up in the view. Anything else is testing implementation, not results, which is a no-no.

Comment: @Craws no, not impossible. You can apply the logic directly on the member as an assertion of expected behavior.

Comment: The business rule regarding the meals is that any given day should have a specific dietary restriction. Thus saying I want to see whether a day has a Saltless meal, is that testing implementation too?

Comment: Perhaps. It depends on what you're testing and how specific you need to be in that test. The point is that you want to test the end result, not any one particular set of logic or implementation.